# How To increase the speed of magento websites

Tags: mysql, performance, .htaccess, magento

I have use some tips like magneto catching feature, disable non used modules, merge css and javascript, disable system log.

so please tell me what can I do more to increase speed.

Answer (score 2):

There are setting in .htaccess file

```
<ifmodule mod_deflate.c>
############################################
## enable apache served files compression
## http://developer.yahoo.com/performance/rules.html#gzip
# Insert filter
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE
# Netscape 4.x has some problems...
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
# Netscape 4.06-4.08 have some more problems
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
# MSIE masquerades as Netscape, but it is fine
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
# Don't compress images
SetEnvIfNoCase Request_URI \.(?:gif|jpe?g|png)$ no-gzip dont-vary
# Make sure proxies don't deliver the wrong content
Header append Vary User-Agent env=!dont-vary
</ifmodule>

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
   Header set Connection keep-alive
</IfModule>

## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 year"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##

FileETag none
Header unset Cookie  
Header unset Set-Cookie

<FilesMatch "!\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$">
    php_value session.cookie_domain example.com
</FilesMatch>
```

I think This Will Help You

Comment: Perfect solution.  Practically tried your answer without requirement for my site and the results are just amazing... If possible I would like to give +10 for ur answer bt it is not possible. So only +1 as of now.. ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can go through the below steps for Magento Optimization:

1. High Performance Dedicated Server. Ex: Amazon EC2 cloud
2. Swap Apache for NGINX
3. Minimize Javascript use
4. Minify and Compressed CSS files
5. ‘Combine CSS’ seeks to reduce the number of HTTP requests made by a
   browser
6. Optimize images
7. Use lazyload for images
8. Specify Image dimensions
9. Combine images into CSS sprites
10. Use a Content Delivery Network (CDN) for delivering static files
     like JS, CSS and Images to offload your server
11. Disable modules/extension which are not required
12. Enable all Magento Caches
13. Use a Full Page Cache / Varnish Cache / Memcache / RedisCache
14. Don’t use layered navigation if you don’t really need it, it needs
     a lot of resources
15. Enable Compilation
16. Limit the number of products on a product overview page.
17. Set only those attribute frontend properties to ‘Yes’ that you’re
     actually going to use. Set all other to ‘No’.
18. Don’t use in quick search, advanced search compare, etc. : Catalog
     -> Attributes -> Manage Atributes -> Frontend Properties.
19. Install Google Page Speed Module
20. Minimize redirects – Minimizing HTTP redirects from one URL to
     another cuts out wait time for users.
21. Prefer asynchronous resources – Fetching resources asynchronously
     prevents those resources from blocking the page load.